# Can you figure out the christmas message?

Tags: letters, seasonal

Some puzzle-makers have decorated their Christmas tree. They have used glue to stick a letter to each Christmas ball. Every letter can only be found on one certain color of Christmas ball. *But oh no*, they used the wrong glue. All the letters have fallen off from the Christmas balls.

Can you figure out which letters belong to which Christmas ball color, and can you figure out the message? (see image below)

These letters have been found under the Christmas tree:
**AAACDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEEFGGHIIIIILLMNNNNNOOORRRRRRRRUUWWY** (amount: 55)

The Christmas tree:
[image]

So, to restate the problem clearly:

- Each letter only appears on **one** certain color
- Multiple letters can share the **same** color
- Spaces are **not** letters (wait what?), spaces are clearly distinguishable on the christmas tree
- A word will always be on just **one** sentence, no mid-way splitting!

Hints: *None yet, but may appear soon (evil Grinch laugh)*

*This question was inspired by the [Dutch General Intelligence and Security Service](https://www.aivd.nl/) [christmas puzzles of 2015](https://www.aivd.nl/onderwerpen/informatiebeveiliging/documenten/publicaties/2015/12/11/kerstpuzzel-2015)*

Comment: errr theres's 16 different letters, but only a few colours??

Comment: yup, so some colours correspond to multiple letters. but no letter corresponds to multiple colours. (Right, Thomas W?)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan exactly, that's right. Read the additional info at the bottom Beastly Gerbil!

Comment: Aaah I misread that. My mistake

Comment: I think I got it. Making sure I got the counts right.

Comment: @DennisMeng uh oh, might have made the sentence to easy then. Im curious!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sentence is:

> How many deer would a reindeer reign if a reindeer could reign deer? (Question mark added by me, of course)

Counts by color:

> Purple (7 total) - C(1), H(1), I(5) 
>  Blue (12 total) - F(1), O(3), R(8) 
>  Orange (5 total) - U(2), W(2), Y(1) 
>  Yellow (13 total) - E(12), M(1) 
>  Light Blue (7 total) - A(3), G(2), L(2) 
>  Red (11 total) - D(6), N(5)